# Is there a way to create qualifier-preserving functions in C?

Tags: c, function, const-correctness, qualifiers

I have a function that accepts a pointer but does not modify the pointed data, but returns the same pointer or a derivative thereof. I could make the pointer `const`:

```
const void *some_read_only_operation(const void *ptr) {
    // Do work with ptr
    return ptr;
}
```

However, this means if I call the function, I will not be able to manipulate the result without a cast, even if the pointer I passed was not `const`. On the contrary, if I make the pointers and return type in the function non `const` then I will need a cast to pass any pointer to the function that is `const`. And I will get a non `const` pointer back so I have broken `const` safety.

Is there any way to create a function in C that repects `const` correctness (`const` in means `const` out and non `const` in means non `const` out) without having to write 2 separate functions? If not, how close can I get?

**Note:** This seems to be the type of question that is likely to have been asked before. I tried to search for duplicates using keywords like *const function return* or *qualifier preserving function* but I could not find any.

Comment: C23 adds `QChar*` for this.

Comment: @Barmar Is `QChar *` a type that can be used in verbatim by users? Or is it a placeholder for the specification of library functions? Is there a way to define `QArbitraryType *` in C23? And how close can I get without C23?

Comment: It's a placeholder used in the specification of standard functions like `strstr()` and `strchr()`. The underlying mechanism is to define generic functions, which ability was added in C11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) for this:

```c
/**
 * Cast a pointer to `void *` while keeping qualifiers, e.g.
 *
 *     struct foo *   => void *
 *     const char *   => const void *
 *     volatile int * => volatile void *
 */
#define VOID_CONVERT(ptr) (1 ? (ptr) : (void *)(ptr))

const void *const_fn(const void *ptr) {
    return ptr;
}

void *non_const_fn(void *ptr) {
    // Re-use the const implementation
    return (void *)const_fn(ptr);
}

#define fn(ptr) _Generic(VOID_CONVERT(ptr), \
    void *: non_const_fn((void *)(ptr)), \
    const void *: const_fn((const void *)(ptr)))
```

Comment: I assume the purpose of `#define VOID_DECAY(ptr) (1 ? (ptr) : (void *)(ptr))` to be a qualifier-preserving conversion to `void *`. Is this correct? Also is there a way that does not entail creating 2 separate functions?

Comment: Tavian Barnes, Nice, yet `VOID_DECAY()`  1) deserves explanation 2) _decay_ sounds too much like array to to address of first element _decay_.  Consider an alternative.

Comment: @user16217248 Have the non-const version call the `const` version.  Still 2 functions, yet 1 of them is very short, possibly `inline`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I suppose that is good enough.

Comment: @user16217248 @chux I have integrated your good suggestions into the answer.  You could also put the `(void *)` cast right in the macro to avoid creating another function.

Comment: @chux Technically it does also perform array-to-pointer "decay," but I renamed it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can return an offset instead of a pointer:

```
#include <stddef.h>


//  Function definition:
ptrdiff_t SomeReadOnlyOperation(const void * const Original)
{
    const void *Derived = Original;
    // Work with Derived.
    return (const char *) Derived - (const char *) Original;
}


…

    //  Function use:
    char *MyPointer = …;
    MyPointer += SomeReadOnlyOperation(MyPointer);
```

You can use units other than `char` for the offset if that is suitable for your application.

Comment: Interesting approach, yet if the derived return value was `NULL`, the offset will not work well.  IOWs, nothing about the original coding goal limited the return pointer's value.  Offset approach works well for pointers to _strings_ and the like where `(const char *) Derived - (const char *) Original` is well defined.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: It is easy enough to designate some sentinel value for the return value. `PTRDIFF_MIN` will work in all practical situations.